# Overriding default save behavior using onsubmit attribute on lightning:recordEditForm gives error for button.find(auraId).submit(fields)

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm dynamically creating `<lightning:recordEditForm>`s and also overriding the default save behavior by using the onsubmit attribute on `lightning:recordEditForm` and `event.preventDefault()`. But when I press the *Save* button, I get the following error:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
> Action failed: c:InteractionNewEditModal$controller$handleSubmit [button.submit is not a function]
> Failing descriptor: {c:InteractionNewEditModal$controller$handleSubmit}

The `<lightning:button` is definitely nested in the `form` element. Here's my code:

Javascript

```
createComponentsFromSObjInfos: function(component, sObjInfos) {
    let newComponents = []

    for (let sObjInfo of sObjInfos) {
        // Outer div
        newComponents.push(
            ['div', {
                class: 'slds-var-m-bottom_medium relative',
                'data-id': sObjInfo.recordId
            }]
        )

        // Spinner
        newComponents.push(
            ['c:Spinner', {
                isSpinning: true,
                'aura:id': 'spin' + sObjInfo.recordId
            }]
        )

        // lightning:recordEditForm
        newComponents.push(
            ['lightning:recordEditForm', {
                objectApiName: sObjInfo.objectApiName,
                recordId: sObjInfo.recordId,
                density: 'comfy',
                onload: component.getReference('c.formLoaded'),
                onsubmit: component.getReference('c.handleSubmit'),
                onsuccess: component.getReference('c.handleSuccess'),
                onerror: component.getReference('c.handleError')
            }]
        )

        // lightning:messages
        newComponents.push(
            ['lightning:messages']
        )

        // c:ModalHeader
        newComponents.push(
            ['c:ModalHeader', {
                showClose: false,
                text: sObjInfo.modalTitle
            }]
        )

        // Modal content div
        newComponents.push(
            ['div', {
                class: 'slds-modal__content slds-var-p-around_large'
            }]
        )

        // c:InteractionEditRecordFields
        newComponents.push(
            ['c:InteractionEditRecordFields', {
                sObjTypeName: sObjInfo.objectApiName,
                recordTypeLabel: sObjInfo.recordTypeLabel
            }]
        )

        // Footer
        newComponents.push(
            ['footer', {
                class: 'slds-modal__footer'
            }]
        )

        // lightning:button
        newComponents.push(
            ['lightning:button', {
                type: 'submit',
                label: 'Save',
                variant: 'brand',
                'aura:id': 'btn' + sObjInfo.recordId
            }]
        )
    }

    return newComponents
},
insertRecordEditComponents: function(component, newComponents) {
    this.createComponents(newComponents)
        .then($A.getCallback((components) => {
            var allComponents = []

            for (let i = 0; i < components.length; i+=9) {
                let div = components[i],
                spinner = components[i + 1],
                recordE = components[i + 2],
                message = components[i + 3],
                modalhd = components[i + 4],
                contdiv = components[i + 5],
                editFld = components[i + 6],
                dfooter = components[i + 7],
                submitb = components[i + 8]

                // Footer
                dfooter.set('v.body', submitb)

                // Modal Content
                contdiv.set('v.body', editFld)

                // Set body of lightning:recordEditForm
                recordE.set('v.body', [
                    message,
                    modalhd,
                    contdiv,
                    dfooter
                ])

                // Set body of outer div
                div.set('v.body', [spinner, recordE])

                allComponents.push(div)
            }

            console.log('allComponents', allComponents)
            component.set('v.body', allComponents)
        }))
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('error', error)
        })
},
handleSubmit : function(component, event, helper) {
    event.preventDefault()

    let id = event.target.closest('[data-id]').dataset.id,
    button = component.find('btn' + id),
    fields = event.getParam('fields')
    console.log('id', id)
    console.log('button', button)
    
    button.submit(fields)
},
```

`id` and `button` are both non-null (they are found properly) but .submit() "is not a function"

[image: visual and html markup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lightning:button` does not have a submit method. See specification in: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:button/specification

Right now, your `handleSubmit` method doesn't change anything in the submitted field data so it should work if you simply remove that method and don't use it as a handler. If you want to keep it then add aura:id (myform in the example below) to your `lightning:recordEditForm` and modify the method to look closer to this:

```
handleSubmit : function(component, event, helper) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var fields = event.getParam('fields');
    // ...
    // here you will do some field changes 
    // ...
    component.find('myform').submit(fields);
},
```

Comment: Wow! That was so stupid I'm tempted to delete the question haha. Thanks for pointing out the obvious! :)